# Improvements in iOS 7.1 for iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad

So the whole internet is full of joy for optimization of the new 7.1 update which makes the OS much more usable on good old iPhone 4. I haven't found anything, though, concerning the iPad 2. Are there any improvements for iPad 2 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read in many user comments that yes it did improve the UX on iPad 2. It's more fluid than before.

Edit : [This french site](http://www.igen.fr/iphone/ios-71-faisons-le-point-110469) confirms it.